# Equivalent of Fetch 'no-cors' mode in XHR or Ajax libraries?

Tags: ajax, cors, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api

Is there a way to write fetch {mode: 'no-cors'} in an existing (and most browsers supported) HTTP request? As an example, I would like to know if it's possible to translate this:

```
fetch(url, { mode: 'no-cors'})
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Into a XMLHttpRequest or Ajax of some sort. I tried several ways and they behave differently - I just want the opaque response that fetch returns.

Thanks!

Comment: The XHR API doesn’t provide a way to specify 'no-cors' mode. And given XHR & Fetch are the only standard HTTP-request APIs supported natively in browsers, that means at the browser level, the only way you can do a  'no-cors'-mode request is by relying on the Fetch API. So if any Ajax library were to provide a method with a 'no-cors' request mode, that library could necessarily only do it by wrapping the Fetch API. But the current versions of all major browsers already support the Fetch API & have for the last 2 years or more. So unless you need to target some really-old browser, just use Fetch

Comment: Thanks for the info. Based on what I've seen and tested, it does not work for IE 10-11 and some mobile browsers. Unfortunately,  I have a high count of users on IE still. I guess I'll have to load the polyfill for those users and see if that will work. So far, no luck.

Comment: Perhaps what you're looking for is `xhr.open(METHOD, URL, true)` (note `true` as the third argument).

Comment: @AndrewTatomyr The third param of `xhr.open()` is whether or not to do the request asynchronously, and the default value is true, so that won't do anything with CORS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open